# How can I handle an event that's raised in New?

Tags: vb.net, events

Testcase:

```
Public Class T
    Public Event A()

    Public Sub New()
        RaiseEvent A()
    End Sub
End Class

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim obj = New T()
        AddHandler obj.A, AddressOf handleA
    End Sub

    Sub handleA()
        Debug.WriteLine("!")
    End Sub
End Module
```

Of course `AddHandler` hasn't run yet when `New` is fired.

So I tried like this:

```
Public Class T
    Public Event A()

    Public Sub New()
        RaiseEvent A()
    End Sub
End Class

Module Module1
    Dim WithEvents obj As T

    Sub Main()
        obj = New T()
    End Sub

    Sub handleA() Handles obj.A
        Debug.WriteLine("!")
    End Sub
End Module
```

But even here it seems the handler isn't registered until after `New` has completed.

However, in real life the event is raised within code that's semantically part of the object initialisation, and I'd really rather not have to create some `Initialize` function.

Do I have any other option?

Comment: @stakx: Thanks for your edit. Unfortunately, you broke the code (`obj =` was deliberate), renamed functions to fit your personal coding style (why?) and the `constructor` tag does not seem at all useful. Also I don't see why a "VB.NET-specific" title is a problem for a VB.NET-specific question. For these reasons I have rolled-back your edit.

Comment: Sure, roll back if you disagree. No problem. Since you seem to be wondering about the "why" of my edit, let me answer briefly: **1.** I did not rename to fit my personal coding style, but to widely accepted and "officially" documented .NET coding guidelines. **2.** How did `Dim obj As New T()` vs. `Dim obj = New T()` break your code? It didn't. Au contraire, your version only works when `Option Infer` is enabled, while the former (`As`) will always work.

Comment: **3.** I changed the title's `New` to "constructor" because I had the same question, but for C#. I figured a wider audience might be interested in your question, and that change would make your question easier to find for non-VB.NET-focused people. **4.** Same for the [tag:constructor] tag; it makes your question easier to find. -- So much for my reasons to edit, but I won't interfere with your rollback. +1 for a good question, anyhow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It makes no sense to put code which raises an event within a constructor, unless some other code which executes within the same constructor is able to register to handle the event (e.g. through some indirect method call). That in turn would require leaking `Me` before the constructor has completed, which is generally a bad idea.

Basically: try to avoid this design. During construction an object shouldn't be visible to the outside world, and that includes event handlers.

Comment: I was afraid of that. The object's initialisation includes performing some activities, some statistics about which I'd like to raise events for.

Comment: Only stuff which should only be done once, and which the rest of the object's behaviour relies upon having been done.

Comment: @Tomalak: But which needs to be exposed before the rest of the object? It sounds fairly odd to me, to be honest. Have you considered creating a factory type which has the event handlers and which is responsible for doing the initial work, broadcasting it and then creating the object?

Comment: No, the stuff that gets initialised doesn't need exposing. I would still like the stats of initialisation progress though; too bad. I am not able to add a factory type at this time, and ideally I don't want to add the complexity, either.

Comment: FYI the constructor is loading and parsing data from a file, data that's required for the object's operation. The events were supposed to inform a form with a progress bar how well this was going.

Comment: @Tomalak: Okay, that sounds like a bad idea to me. Long-running constructors are generally a bit of a design smell. Refactor the loading into a separate method (either a static method in that class or an instance method in a separate class) and then pass in the results to the constructor. That will end up a lot cleaner, IMO.

Comment: I don't really get how they're any worse than a long-running non-constructor function. I also don't understand why events can't be supported here (though I do understand why a reference to the object under construction can't/shouldn't be passed out in one).

Comment: @Tomalak: During a constructor, an object is half-formed. That's not a nice state to work in. There could still be derived class constructors still to run, executing any virtual methods is dodgy etc. You could pass an event handler into the constructor if you must... but otherwise, how would you expect anything else to subscribe to the event?

Comment: Because if I can pass an event handler into the constructor, why can't I raise an event handled by a handler elsewhere, which is functionally the same thing? (But neater to write)

Comment: @Tomalak: Because you're doing the work *in* the constructor, before the event handler gets subscribed. It's like putting on a play in the green room instead of on the stage - the audience can't see what's going on!

Comment: No, I get that, but I don't fully understand _why_ it works that way. Sure in a perfect world `New` would be entirely blackboxed and nothing to do with the object would have anything to do with the outside world until the completion of construction. But, in practice, if I can pass a handler in myself like in Enigmativity, then I ought to be able to use events to do the same thing! I'm sure I can't be the only one who would like to raise events _about_ construction _during_ construction! Oh well.. :(

Comment: @Tomalak: Well, it's not something I've heard before... but the reason you *can't* use events to do the same thing is that the constructor caller would have to *have* an instance of your object in order to subscribe to the event... and by the time the object is constructed, it's too late. You need to understand that your second code is exactly the same as the first - it's just the VB compiler is adding the handler for you, when you assign a value to `obj`... which isn't done until after construction.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jon about putting events into constructors - specifically because the standard event pattern does expose the instance of the sender in the event call and, as Jon rightly says, this is a bad idea.

However, it's not a bad idea if you only pass out values. And you can do that easily.

Try this:

```
Public Class T
    Public Sub New(a As Action)
        a()
    End Sub
End Class

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim obj = New T(AddressOf handleA)
    End Sub

    Sub handleA()
        Debug.WriteLine("!")
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks. I like events because `T` needs no knowledge of any specific handlers, and I definitely want to keep that! :)

Comment: @Tomalak - Then I don't think there's any way to do what you want. Keep in mind that events and actions are both just delegates. One is safe for you to use and the other is not.